# Rails nested joins with third Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join

I have 3 models.

User.rb

```
has_many :user_cards
```

UserCard.rb

```
belongs_to :CardGroup
```

I want to get all users, with cards and the CardGroup information in one single query.

```
 User.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN user_cards ON user_cards.user_id = users.id AND user_cards.created_at BETWEEN '#{@start_time.to_s(:db)}' AND '#{@end_time.to_s(:db)}'")
 .group('users.id, users.mobile, user_cards.user_id, user_cards.bin)
         .select(
      'users.id AS uid, users.name AS uname, users.mobile AS umobile,' \
      'count(distinct(user_cards.id)) AS total_cards, \
      'user_cards.bin AS card_bins'
    )
```

Now, I want to join the third model CardGroup as well and get user_card.card_group.name in the above query.

How can I do it with nested join / any other way?

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: We use Rails 5.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should use snake case in ruby.

```rb
belongs_to :card_group
```

Second, this part of your `join` statement would be better off in a `where` clause.

```sql
AND user_cards.created_at BETWEEN '#{@start_time.to_s(:db)}' AND '#{@end_time.to_s(:db)}'"
```

Third, the join query itself is more readable in Ruby. That's why you put the relation on the model in the first place. So replace:

```sql
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_cards ON user_cards.user_id = users.id
```

with

```rb
User.left_outer_joins(:user_cards)
```

Now adding a 3rd model joined through the 2nd is as easy as:

```rb
User.left_outer_joins(user_cards: :card_group)
```